# Conditionally change CSS class in Razor view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to change the CSS class of the `<div>` tag with the 'forumChild' class. It has to change every 3 loops of the foreach loop.

Is there a way to do this from within the control?

```
<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {               
                <div class="ForumChild">

                    <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />

                    <br />
                            @foreach (var comment in item.Blog.comment)
                            {

                                var db = new ACapture.Models.ACaptureDB();

                                var Name = from p in db.Profile.AsEnumerable()
                                           where (p.AccountID == comment.AccountID)
                                           select p;                            
                            <section>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">@foreach (var y in Name)
                                                                              { @(y.FirstName + " " + y.LastName + ":");
                                                                              }</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        @comment.Commentation 
                                    </div>
                            </section>
                            }
                </div>                
            }
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For anyone visiting this old question. CSS can handle nth child classes see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp you dont need to code conditional nth loops anymore

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
 @{
   int counter=0;
 }
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 { 
   counter++;
   <div class="@(counter<=3 ? "classRed":"classBlue")">
       <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
       //other markup also here

   </div>  
    if (counter == 6)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }

 }
```

Where `classRed` and `classBlue` are the CSS classes

Comment: if I have multiple calsses except 2 , what can I do here ?

Answer (score 5):

How we handle this issue:

1) you need to create helper method that will return css class by some code.

```
string GetDivClass(int code)
{
  var classes = new [] {"first", "second", "third"};
  return classes[code];
}
```

2) create counter/index and increment it in the loop each time.

3) invoke helper method like `GetDivClass(index % 3)` at the *div* element.

PS

It is only POC, so don't use it in a real application (you need to add a validation logic and move 'classes' initialization to another place).

Comment: With your example, it might be best to do the modulo operation inside the function.  That way the caller doesn't need to know how many items it has, and you could also add more items in the future without breaking existing code.

Comment: Good remark, but it will be tricky to understand on layout what this method returns actualy. Maybe it will be better to add some kind of css class group name to the method (GetDivClass(string cssClassesGroup, int code). 
).

Answer (score 2):

You can write any code you like into a Razor view, so to do what you're thinking of, you could do something like this (I left out most of the inner stuff):

```
@{
    var className = "ForumChild";
}
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = Model[i];
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            className = GetNewClassName(); // Or whatever
        <div class="@className">
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add a counter variable to will start with 1 and increment in loop. Check with if statement is true by % and change the class name

```
@{ int counter = 1;}

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{

if( (counter % 3) ==0 )
{
 <div class="ChangedName">
}
else
{
 <div class="ForumChild">
}
i++;
```

Comment: this is not supported in razor, because it will complain about unmatched tags