# How to pass parameters to @Html.Partial and read them into the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a  portion of code for Navigation Bar in the header of the website.

I repeat it within of several views.
The code is almost equal for all views, change just for setting css class "active" for setting the background color of `<li>` TAG.

**Partial Views**

```
 @Model String
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li>
                    <a href="MainPage">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        MainPage
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="SectionSummary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Summary
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Check">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Check
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li  class="(@Model=="Print")?"active":"">
                    <a href="Print">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Print
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I call it in the views in this way:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PSANavigationBar.cshtml")
```

I would to pass a parameter to `@Html.Partial` and then in the PartialView to test a value and flagging `class="active"` when occurs a condition!

For example:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PSANavigationBar.cshtml", "Print")
```

in the view, something like this:

```
        </li>
         <li  class="(@Model=="Check")?"active":"">
            <a href="Check">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                Check
            </a>
        </li>
         <li  class="(@Model=="Print")?"active":"">
            <a href="Print">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
```

but it doesn't work!
How can I do?

Many thanks to all.

Comment: do you get an error when you build it?

Comment: No Error in building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are calling the partial view looks okay, you just need to change the way you choose your class:

```
<li class="@(Model == "Check" ? "active":"")">
```

the `Model` is how you receive your parameter, and this is a way you can choose a class within a razor condition. You can see [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view) of how too choose your class within a condition with asp mvc razor.

You should have something like this:

```
@model String
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li>
                    <a href="MainPage">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        MainPage
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="SectionSummary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Summary
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Check">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Check
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li  class="@(Model=="Print"?"active":"")">
                    <a href="Print">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                        Print
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Please notice that `@` is before the parenthesis `(` not after it in class.

Comment: I'll modify the source in the question...because nothing errors in building and it doesn.t work

Comment: Ok...I modified properly the source.
Now I see "Print String" in the page content!!!

Comment: Ok! Model replaced with model...but it'doesn't work the same ("Print String" now is not visible)

Comment: @Charles my fault, it was a typo at `)` position, can you try again?

Comment: Thank you very much my friend!