# ASP.NET MVC razor: conditional attribute in CSS block

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can I use if condition in style tag like this?

```
<style>
    @@media (min-width: 765px) {
    html,body 
       {
        min-width: auto;
        width: 100%;
        @{
            if (ViewBag.type == "pic")
            {
                @:min-height:100vh;
                @:height:auto;
            }
            else {
                @:height: 100vh;
            }
          }
       }
    }
</style>
```

Or I should use CSS directly in HTML?

Comment: why you want condition in css you can try to apply on html tags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view

Comment: This CSS is for mobile device.Maybe I should write in difference file then dynamic load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your css in css files and target specific classes instead of loading files conditionally.
Then you can use Razor to include conditional classes on your tags. Something like:

```
@{
    var imgType = ViewBag.type == "mobile"?"for-mobile":"for-desktop";
}

<img class="@imgType" src="..."/>
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.for-mobile{
      min-height:100vh;
      height:auto;
}

.for-desktop{
     height: 100vh;
}
```