# Concatenation of strings in Razor MVC 5 for "class" attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application for a local inventory. This app shows items on a page with buttons to deliver the items.

[image]

I want the "Scarica" buttons to be greyed-out when items are not available, so I thought I could just delete the `btn-info` attribute and that should've done the trick, so I changed the relevant lines of code in the view from this

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ScaricaItem", "Scarico"))
    {
        string Disabilitato = "";
        if (i.Qty == 0)
        {
            Disabilitato += "disabled";
        }

        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => @i.Item.Modello)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Scarica" @Disabilitato />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ScaricaItem", "Scarico"))
    {
        string Disabilitato = "";
        string Classe = "";
        if (i.Qty == 0)
        {
            Disabilitato += "disabled";
            Classe = "btn";
        }
        else
        {
            Classe = "btn btn-info";
        }

        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => @i.Item.Modello)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class=@Classe value="Scarica" @Disabilitato />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

but now I have all the buttons greyed-out because the `btn-info` attribute value is treated as if it was an attribute itself

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" btn-info="" value="Scarica">
```

I also tried

```
<input type="submit" class=@(Classe) value="Scarica" @Disabilitato />
```

and

```
<input type="submit" class=@(String.Format("{0}", Classe)) value="Scarica" @Disabilitato />
```

but nothing changes.

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: You need to quote the attribute - `class="@Classe"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. Why didn't you answer? :)

Comment: Was trying to find a dupe :)

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view) is similar, but not so obvious.