# How do I change the color of a Modal Dialog based on model value in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a modal dialog that I want to change the color of the modal title based on the value in the model.  How can I best accomplish this?  `Model.AlertType.Description` contains the value that I want to use to change the title color (critical = red, warning = yellow, Info = green)

EDIT: I don't have alot of experience in this area, so I am not sure what I am missing. I changed the div class to match what I found at the following link as a guide: 
 https://www.bootply.com/s6x5oKLiDG

```
@model AgRSys.Models.Alerts

<div class="container">
  <div id="display-alerts-modal-dialog" class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
            <button type="button" class="modal-header-close close" data- 
                dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModal-label">Model.AlertType.Description </h4>

        </div>

        <div id="modal-body" class="form-group modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DisplayAlert", ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"), new { LID = Model.RelatedId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "alerts-grid-body", OnFailure = "onFailure", OnSuccess = "onDisplayAlertSuccess", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
            {
                <div id="modal-body" class="form-group modal-body">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alert, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Alert, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alert, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I would suggest adding a class to your `h4` element depending on the value of that property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally change CSS class in Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view)

Comment: I added a link to a site that I was using as a guide to do something similar, but since my experience is limited, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  Your answer was on the right track, I just wasn't adding the styles in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that `Model.AlertType.Description` is a string and its values correspond ones at the [link](https://www.bootply.com/s6x5oKLiDG), just try following Razor:

```
<div class="modal-header modal-header-@(Model.AlertType.Description.ToLower().Trim())">
```

This line assumes that `Model.AlertType.Description` returns following value:

**`success, primary, info, warning, danger`**

> *This is the view cshtml code fixed:*

```
@model AgRSys.Models.Alerts

<div class="container">
  <div id="display-alerts-modal-dialog" class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-header-@(Model.AlertType.Description.ToLower().Trim())"> @*Here it is the fix*@
            <button type="button" class="modal-header-close close" data- 
                dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModal-label">Model.AlertType.Description </h4>

        </div>

        <div id="modal-body" class="form-group modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DisplayAlert", ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"), new { LID = Model.RelatedId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "alerts-grid-body", OnFailure = "onFailure", OnSuccess = "onDisplayAlertSuccess", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
            {
                <div id="modal-body" class="form-group modal-body">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alert, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Alert, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alert, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> *It needs to append to main.css file following lines:*

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.modal-header-success {
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-warning {
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-danger {
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-info {
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-primary {
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #428bca;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: changed my div class to what you suggested, but no change in results.

Comment: I did try changing the two lines like this:    <div class="modal-content panel-info">
            <div class="modal-header panel-heading">.  That will change the color of the heading, but now to convert the "critical" in my model to set the color to panel-dangerous (red)

Comment: I re-edited the answer with all pre-conditions well specified. It is very important include css classes reported in the link you provided otherwise this solution doesn't work and also it is important that alert.description returns values showed in the answer

Comment: I have appended the statements to my site.css file.  The description should return warning, info, and critical.  I renamed one of the classes to modal-header-critical.  still am not getting it to work.

Comment: I noticed a missing closing div, fixed the view code, try now

Answer (score 0):

Once I added the new styles directly to the file, it fixed the issue.  I had appended them to another .CSS file in the application, but it affected the font styles of the other fields in the application.